# std::make_unique as workaround for temporary object not binding to non const reference in C++

Tags: c++, reference, temporary-objects

In the code snippet below, the call mc.function1() succeeds with default value being passed to function1.

I am wondering how the visual studio does not consider *std::make_unique< SomeClass >() as temporary object. Where as, if I set SomeClass() as default value, then visual studio correctly catches it as compile time error, since it is a temporary object which we are trying to bind to non const reference.

Why does Visual Studio 2019 considers *std::make_unique< SomeClass >() as non temporary object?

According to C++ ISO standards, is *std::make_unique< SomeClass >() considered as temporary object?

Or is compiler simply being lenient with it?

```
class SomeClass
{
};

class MyClass
{
public:

    void function1 (SomeClass &obj = *std::make_unique<SomeClass>()) { }
    //void function2 (SomeClass &obj = SomeClass()) { } //compile error
};

int main()
{
    MyClass mc;
    mc.function1();
}
```

function1 below compiles and executes fine.

```
void function1 (SomeClass &obj = *std::make_unique<SomeClass>()) { }
```

I think it should not compile, since *std::make_unique() is temporary object which is  being bound to non const reference. But it builds and runs fine.

Comment: `void function3 (const SomeClass &obj = SomeClass())`

Comment: And "builds fine" doesn't mean the code actually works. Your reference will be left dangling as the temporary object will be promptly destructed.

Comment: Lifeteme of temporary ends when expression is completed evaluation. So your default argument will live as long as function call is completed. Also you made this over-complicated: `void function3 (const SomeClass &obj = {})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not an object can be bound to a reference has nothing to do with whether or not it is a temporary object. It is purely a matter of what the value category of the expression used to initialize the reference is. If the value category is lvalue, then the lvalue reference can be bound to the object that the expression refers to.

`operator*` of `std::unique_ptr` has a lvalue reference as return type. A function call to a function returning a lvalue reference is an lvalue. So a lvalue reference can be bound to the object that the result of the `*` refers to.

`std::unique_ptr` is not special in any way here. You can write your own function that will do it:

```
template<typename T>
T& as_lvalue(T&& t) {
    return t;
}
```

Now you can write

```
SomeClass& x = as_lvalue(/*whatever*/);
```

It doesn't matter what value category `/*whatever*/` has, the reference can now bind to it.

The rule that you can't bind a rvalue to a non-`const` lvalue reference is there purely as a matter to protect you, because most of the time it is semantically wrong to do so and/or there are clearer alternatives (e.g. `const` lvalue reference or rvalue reference). If you want to ignore that protection, C++ won't stop you.

But consider whether you *really* want to do that. Even if you manage to bind a reference to a temporary object, that generally won't extend the lifetime of the temporary. For example if `/*whatever*/` above refers to a temporary object, the lifetime of that temporary object will end after the line initializing the reference. So the reference will immediately be dangling.

Similarly in your example the temporary object created with `std::make_unique` will live only until the end of the function call. If you store the reference somewhere else or return it from the function, it will be dangling. So, what is the point of being able to modify it through the reference (non-`const` lvalue reference), if the caller can never use the value your store into it? It can just be a `const` lvalue reference instead.

Comment: int* arr = new int[1];
 arr[0] = 1;

 std::unique_ptr<int[]> ptr(new int[1]{10});
 *ptr = arr; // error: rvalue

In this case operator* does not return lvalue.

Comment: The return type of operator* for std::unique_ptr is an lvalue if the managed object is an lvalue reference. Otherwise, it is an rvalue.

Comment: @PrasadPatil Please enclose code with `\`` when typing comments, otherwise it won't render properly and I can't see what you meant to type. But I don't know what you mean, [`std::unique_ptr::operator*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*) always returns a lvalue reference for the single-object variant and doesn't exist for the array variant.

Comment: I think, *std::make_unique<SomeClass>() is an rvalue, because it returns a temporary object.

Comment: @PrasadPatil `std::make_unique<SomeClass>()` is a rvalue (specifically prvalue) expression because `std::make_unique` has a non-reference return type. But `*std::make_unique<SomeClass>()` is an lvalue expression because `std::unqiue_ptr::operator*`'s return type is a lvalue reference. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category (fixed link).